# Select max value

Tags: sql, max, innodb

I'm struggling to find a way to get the max value per row in my query.
My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT f.FID, f.name, f.description, t.TID, t.topic, p.timestamp, u.username, u.ID
FROM forum f 
LEFT JOIN threads t ON t.FID=f.FID AND t.TID=(SELECT p.TID FROM posts p WHERE p.timestamp=(SELECT MAX(p.timestamp) FROM posts p))
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.TID=t.TID
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID=p.authorID
```

**Some simple explanation**: every post is bound to a thread's TID, every thread is bound to a forum's FID.
What I want to do is get the latest post (highest value for timestamp) from every forum, but I'm kinda stuck here.
A picture of how it looks in the current state:
[image: forum image]

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/

Comment: More on [groupwise max](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with an additional join to a derived table that contains the maximum timestamp value per `TID`:

```
SELECT f.FID, f.name, f.description, t.TID, t.topic, 
       p.timestamp, u.username, u.ID
FROM forum f 
LEFT JOIN threads t ON t.FID = f.FID 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT TID, MAX(timestamp) AS max_timestamp
   FROM posts
   GROUP BY TID
) AS x ON t.TID = x.TIP
LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.TID = t.TID AND p.timestamp = x.max_timestamp
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID = p.authorID
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to use **inner** join. Then we can identify last Post for each Thread or Forum (see `lp`) and use it as a filter.

---

Last Post from each Thread:

```
SELECT
    f.FID, f.name, f.description, t.TID, t.topic, p.timestamp, u.username, u.ID
FROM forum f
INNER JOIN threads t ON t.FID=f.FID
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.TID=t.TID
INNER JOIN users u ON u.ID=p.authorID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TID, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY TID
) lp ON lp.TID = t.TID AND lp.timestamp = p.timestamp
```

---

Last Post from each Forum:

```
SELECT
    f.FID, f.name, f.description, t.TID, t.topic, p.timestamp, u.username, u.ID
FROM forum f
INNER JOIN threads t ON t.FID=f.FID
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.TID=t.TID
INNER JOIN users u ON u.ID=p.authorID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ft.FID, MAX(fp.timestamp) AS timestamp
    FROM posts fp
    INNER JOIN threads ft ON fp.TID=ft.TID
    GROUP BY ft.FID
) lp ON lp.FID = f.FID AND lp.timestamp = p.timestamp
```

Comment: This only shows the forum with the latest post, because it only selects the rows which have the max value for timestamp. Aka it doesn't show the 'test' forum: http://i.imgur.com/etS0wN3.png

Comment: That might be due to test Post being artificially generated without proper User and possibly even Forum. Please try running subquery on it's own. You'll notice it produce max timestamp for each FID / TID. Please verify data integrity.

Comment: You can also try replacing `INNER` with `LEFT` `JOIN users` just for the testing.

Comment: Well I eventually went with a new query inside the while loop, my query understanding is just too limited to get it working like this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Not at all. Cycle should be fine. Whatever works for you is the right way to do it: you would be the one to develop and debug it.